# RegEx: split text in to words preserve line breacks

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

`"This is the\nstring with\nline breaks\n"`

I need to get:

`[This, is, the\n, string, with\n, line, breaks\n`]

When I use .split(/\s{1,}/) - \n line breaks disappear. How to preserve them?

Multiple spaces need to be considered

Comment: Please explain how you'd want `"This\n\n\n"` to be split (`["This\n\n\n"]` or `["This\n"]` or `["This\n", "\n", "\n"]`) in case my answer isn't behaving as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a `match` will give you what you want

```
"This is the\nstring with\nline breaks\n".match( /([^\s]+\n*|\n+)/g );

// ["This", "is", "the\n", "string", "with\n", "line", "breaks\n"]
```

`[^\s]+` means as many non-space as possible (one or more),
`\n*` means as many new lines as possible (0 or more),
`|` means *OR*,
`\n+` means as many new lines as possible (one or more).

Comment: This does exactly the same as `.split(' ')` (Or so my console says). Seems like overcomplicating it.

Comment: No. Look at index 2 and 3. This method splits after the `\n`, `"the\n", "string"`. `.split(' ')` doesn't, `"the\nstring", "with\nline"`

Comment: @Bruno you're quite imaginative, I like that. Updated again. We will see what behaviour OP wants if an answer to my comment appears and I'll modify the `+` and `*` as required.

Comment: @PaulS. That's brilliant. +1

Answer (score 1):

By making the split a capture group they will appear in the results array. You can then massage that :

```
 "This is the\nstring with\nline breaks\n".split(/(\s+)/);
```

Results in :

```
["This", " ", "is", " ", "the", "\n", "string", " ", "with", "\n", "line", " ", 
 "breaks", "\n", ""]
```

I'll leave as an exercise the manipulation of this array will produce your requested result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
.split(/ +/); // (/ +/ to take multiple spaces into account.)
```

Because:

```
"This is the\nstring with\nline breaks\n".split(' ');
```

Returns:

```
["This", "is", "the
string", "with
line", "breaks
"]
```

You might not literally see `"\n"` in those strings, as they're rendered as actual line-breaks instead, in the console.

Answer (score 0):

split simply by space

```
.split(" ");
```

Comment: What about multiple spaces?